# Connect UIstepper and UIlabel

Tags: ios, user-interface, uilabel, uistepper

How do I connect an UIstepper with an UIlabel so that the value from "+" or "-" in UIstepper increases/decreases the value/number in UIlabel? The app has only one viewvontroller and should allow users to simply count up (or down) days.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to do this automatically. Add your label and stepper. Setup an action to handle the stepper.

In your implementation of this action method, increment or decrement an instance variable of type `int` to keep the current count. After getting the new count, convert the value to a string and use the new string to set the label's text.